# Nomethod Error in TakeAssementController#start

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass Extracted source around **line
>   42**.

This is the part of my `take_assement.controller.rb` file where it is showing error.
The line I started from is **line 36**. So accordingly **line 42** has an issue.

```
def start
if current_user.taken_any_assessment?.all?
  redirect_to user_root_path
else
  Portal.all.sort_by(&:display_order).each do |portal|
    if !current_user.taken_assessment
(portal.current_assessment(current_user))
      @assessment =       Assessment.find(portal.current_assessment(current_user).id)
      if !@assessment.has_student_taken_this_assessment?(current_user)
        AssessmentResult.create!(student: current_user, assessment: @assessment, last_question: 0)
        @question = @assessment.questions.first
      else
        last_position = AssessmentResult.where(student: current_user, assessment: @assessment).first
        @question = @assessment.questions.where(position: last_position.last_question+1).first
      end
```

Comment: `portal.current_assessment(current_user)` is coming up as nil for some values of `Portal` objects. Hence, `portal.current_assessment(current_user).id` is throwing a `undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass ` error message.

Comment: Ya I figured that out. So how do I fix it?

Comment: Figure out which value of `Portal` object is giving a nil output, and make sure it does not do so. Or exclude it from calling the statement with `id`. Use `puts` statements to run through the execution.

Comment: I used puts statement after the if statement and excluded the line which was causing problems but it still did not work.